# How to lint HTML file using the vim ale plugin?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-html, plugin-ale

Install ale with pathogen.

```
 cd ~/.vim/bundle
 git clone https://github.com/w0rp/ale.git
```

My setting for ale in `.vimrc`.

```
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 1
let g:ale_set_highlights = 0
```

The target html file named `test.html` to check with ale.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" herf="" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The real wrong syntax is a simple word `herf` whose right format is `href`.
Open with vim installed ale.
It is no matter to let title empty.
`ale` can't check out the real wrong syntax,a wrong spelled word.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that ALE is not itself a linter, it is an interface to "supported [...] tools which have been correctly installed." Given that you've only described installing ALE, and that you refer to "ALE [not checking] out the real wrong syntax," I think you may have missed a step. See [Supported Languages and Tools](https://github.com/w0rp/ale#1-supported-languages-and-tools) for a handful of HTML linters that ALE supports.